# Conjecture for the maximum number of rooms.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction, conjectures

[image]

The puzzle I have is essentially this, but for $n$ rows.For this instance of $n=5$, quick tallying reveals the answer to be $21$. For $n=4$, it is $13$. For $n=3$, it is $7$. For $n=2$ it is $3$. And for $n=1$, it is obviously $1$. I conjectured a formula to calculate the maximum number of rooms: $n^2 - n +1$. I have tested this formula upto $n=7$ and it works. (I don't want to test anymore, too lazy) Now it is my understanding that all conjectures must be proven, but I don't know how to prove mine. I'm thinking induction, but as I haven't formally learnt it yet, I'm not well versed in induction. I'd appreciate it if you could show me *a* proof. It need not be induction. Thanks :)

Comment: It may be possible to prove this by induction, but this doesn't look like an easy problem at first glance.

Comment: @David Will induction for this require a visual aid? That is, will it be required to draw a triangle with n rows and then one with n+1 rows?

Comment: It's not possible to say before you have a particular proof by induction in mind. If it was obvious that, in order to find an optimal pat at level $n+1$, you could split the path into a part in an $n$-triangle and a part in the remaining row, then it might be possible to do this by induction. I don't yet see why that would be the case.

Comment: @David The path outlined by my conjecture is as follows: start from the bottom side and proceed to the opposite side, but do not go to the last triangle, instead lift up to the next row. This way, one triangle is lost at every row. This path is intuitive for low values of $n$; it becomes less obvious if you start with a high value.

Comment: You can't escape the necessity of *proving* that that is optimal. At the moment, I don't see the solution to the problem, so I can't give hints.

Comment: @David Ah yes. Are there any similar problems where a path is proven to be optimal? If so, could you point me to some? I'd like to get some insight into it. PS. my path _seems_ to be optimal. So _assuming_ that it is optimal (which it may not be as you said), is there a way to prove my conjecture?

Comment: the longest possible path in a bipartite graph is $2\min(|c_1|,|c_2|)+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider coloring the triangles as follows:

[image]

In any path you can only move from a dark triangle to a light triangle or vice versa. In a triangle with $n$ rows there are $\sum_{k=1}^n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ dark triangles and $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}=\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$ light triangles (fewer than the number of light triangles). So the maximum theoretical length of a path is $2\cdot \frac{(n-1)n}{2}+1=(n-1)n+1=n^2-n+1$ triangles. This number is obtained by considering a path that starts at a dark triangle, then moves to light, dark, light, etc. until all $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$ light triangles have been visited (this covers $2\cdot \frac{(n-1)n}{2}$ triangles), then finally moving to a dark triangle (hence the $+1$). After this you cannot visit any more triangles, as the dark triangle is only adjacent to light triangles, and you've already visited them all. Note this doesn't prove that such a path exists.

Combining this with your explicit construction of a path that covers $n^2-n+1$ triangles, this proves that $n^2-n+1$ is the optimal number for all $n$. This can be proved by induction. For $n=1$, there is a path of length $1=1^1-1+1$, which establishes the base case. Now suppose that for some integer $n-1$ ($n \geq 2$), the triangle of $n-1$ rows contains a path of length $(n-1)^2-(n-1)+1$ which does not visit a room more than once, and suppose additionally that the path ends in one of the bottom corners of the triangle. Add an $n$th row to the triangle, and consider extending extending the path by moving directly downward from the last triangle and straight across to the opposite corner of the bottom row. Note that we visit all of the light triangles in the bottom row, of which there are $n-1$, and all but one of the dark triangles in the bottom row, of which there are $n$. So we've added $2(n-1)$ triangles to the path. Thus the path has length 
$$(n-1)^2-(n-1)+1+2(n-1)=(n^2-2n+1)-n+1+1+(2n-2)=n^2-n+1.$$
So the triangle with $n$ rows has a path of length $n^2-n+1$ which visits does not visit any triangle more than once, and the path ends in one of the bottom corners of the triangle. (It's important to prove that the extended path ends in a bottom corner if we include that as part of the induction hypothesis; otherwise we may not be able to apply that method of extending the path again.)

Comment: The intuition you described for the induction is exactly what led me to the conjecture in the first place, that is, one triangle will be lost at each row if you move down to the next one!!! Great answer, but, seeing as I'm not yet educated in even basic number theory (I'd love to learn it, but I'm a busy high school sophomore) could you point me to some article or something that explains how you arrived to the "maximum theoretical path" and the closed-form formulae for the dark and light triangles? I'm sure you could answer it yourself, but I'd think the comments don't have enough space...

Comment: I don't have such a resource as I wrote this argument myself. I can try to provide some explanation. For the max theoretical path: I could have instead said that every path looks like $DLDL\cdots D$ or $LDLD\cdots D$ or $DLDL\cdots L$ or $LDLD\cdots L$, where $D=\text{dark}$, $L=\text{light}$. Since there are fewer $L$ triangles than $D$, we are constrained by how many $L$s there are. So the longest possible path (in theory) is the one that looks like $DLDL\cdots D$ and covers all the $L$ triangles. As for the sums, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number.

Comment: Yes, but I feel as David stated in the comments to the question, that the fact that _is_ in fact the optimal path should be proven rigorously. I know that it probably is, because it's the most exhaustive, but I feel there should be some way to prove it.

Comment: Also, just for my curiosity, could you provide an induction proof? As I said, I haven't studied it, so I'm not very good at it.

Comment: The "longest theoretical path" argument is rigorous, but as I noted it does not prove the existence of such a path. It merely says that whatever the longest path is, it's no longer than $n^2-n+1$. I'll edit my answer to add the induction proof.

Comment: The induction proof is very nice.